# how to asses widget which is in the list?

Tags: flutter

I want to assess widgets in the form of list in navigator.push but a error is popping up "Error: The getter 'index' isn't defined for the class 'Textwidget'."  so what can i do to solve this

```
    class Textwidget extends StatelessWidget {
     late String text;
     Textwidget(this.text);

     List<Widget> gridMembersPath = [
      wewre(),

           ];

    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return InkWell(
         onTap: () {
         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                  return (gridMembersPath[index]);
                }));
      },
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
    child: Text(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.grey),
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
 }
```

Comment: you have not defined `index`. What is its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out for the arguments property in Navigator class.
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments
do upvote if helpful